# Disable button in cocoa application OS X

Tags: swift, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I would like to have the submit button enabled once some fields on a form have been validated. Currently the preview function works great, preview button provides the validation I need. Working on Xcode 7 and swift 2. I would really appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction. Below is the code I currently have:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var projectFlag = false
    var descriptionFlag = false
    var releaseFlag = false

    // Fields
    @IBOutlet weak var projectNumberTextField:NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var projectDescriptionTextField:NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseFolderNameTextField:NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField:NSTextField!

    // Labels for preview
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label5: NSTextField!

    // Quit Button :: Quits the application
    @IBAction func quitButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }

    // Preview button behavior
    @IBAction func previewButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Project Number :: 
        let project = projectNumberTextField.stringValue
        label1.stringValue = "\(project)"
        if (label1.stringValue == "00-0000") {
            label1.stringValue = "Project Number is not valid"
            label1.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
            projectFlag = false
        } else {
        label1.textColor = NSColor.blackColor()
        projectFlag = true
        }

        // Project Description :: Name, 2016
        let description = projectDescriptionTextField.stringValue
        label2.stringValue = "\(description)"
        if (label2.stringValue == "Name, 2016") {
            label2.stringValue = "Enter a valid project description"
            label2.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
            descriptionFlag = false
        } else {
            label2.textColor = NSColor.blackColor()
            descriptionFlag = true
        }

        // Folder Release Name :: RELEASE_NAME
        let release = releaseFolderNameTextField.stringValue
        label3.stringValue = "\(release)"
        if (label3.stringValue == "RELEASE_NAME") {
            label3.stringValue = "Enter a valid folder release name"
            label3.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
            releaseFlag = false
        } else {
            label3.textColor = NSColor.blackColor()
            releaseFlag = true
        }


        // Password :: If needed
        let password = passwordTextField.stringValue
        label4.stringValue = "\(password)"

        // Preview :: Code format for txt file
        let preview = "\(project)|"+"\(description)|"+"\(release)|"+"\(password)/"
        label5.stringValue = "\(preview)"
        }

    // Submit button behavior
    @IBAction func submitButton(Sender: AnyObject) {


    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }


    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: I tidied up the formatting on the code block, always double check when pasting in the all of the code is formatted - to do so it must have four spaces - "    " between the left margin and the start of the text.

Comment: Use the NSTextField textDidChange (or similar) delegate methods to call the validation function, in there you set the button (which you need an outlet for) to enabled of everything is valid.